# C# Aliasing Type Constraints in a Generic Method for Reuse

Tags: c#, generics

Take a look at at the code below.

```
void Foo1<T>() where T : struct, IBar1, IBar2, IBar3 {}
void Foo2<T>() where T : struct, IBar1, IBar2, IBar3 {}
void Foo3<T>() where T : struct, IBar1, IBar2, IBar3 {}
```

How can I alias the constraints on the right side of each declaration so that those declarations can become shorter and more readable?

Conceptually, what I'm after should look similar to this (not valid C# code):

```
MyConstraint<T> = T : struct, IBar1, IBar2, IBar3;
void Foo1<T>() where T : MyConstraint {}
void Foo2<T>() where T : MyConstraint {}
void Foo3<T>() where T : MyConstraint {}
```

That `T : struct` is the most crucial part for my use case.

If there is no such grammar in C#, what alternatives do you suggest to reduce the clutter here?

Comment: There is no such syntax in C# (at least, for now). But you can create a type which match the constraint `where T : struct, IBar1, IBar2, IBar3` and use it as generic constraint. There is an open issue [#1239](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1239) for generic type aliases

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a 'using alias = class' with generic types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936941/using-a-using-alias-class-with-generic-types)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Unfortunately it doesn't. Maybe it is not possible yet.

Comment: Yes, the linked GitHub proposal is still open