# C#: Extension Methods not accessible with aliased using directive

Tags: c#, extension-methods

The following code compiles:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

class Dummy()
{
    void DummyFunction(ClientContext ctx, ListCollection lists)
    {
        Context.Load(lists, lc => lc.Include(l => l.DefaultViewUrl);
    }
}
```

However, when switching to an aliased using, there is a problem with the Include function, which is an extension method:

```
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

class DummyAliased()
{
    void DummyFunction(SP.ClientContext ctx, SP.ListCollection lists)
    {
        /* Does not compile: */
        Context.Load(lists, lc => lc.Include(l => l.DefaultViewUrl);
        /* Compiles (not using function as generic) */
        Context.Load(lists, lc => SP.ClientObjectQueryableExtension.Include(lc, l => l.DefaultViewUrl));
    }
}
```

The Include function can still be used, but not as an extension method. Is there any way to use it as an extension method without un-aliasing the using directive?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337453 asks _why this doesn't work_. I am asking _is there a better workaround_ than what I've shown.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not before C# 6... but in C# 6 you can use:

```
using static Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObjectQueryableExtension;

using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
```

The first of these will pull in *just* the static members of `ClientObjectQueryableExtension` available, without anything to do with the rest of the namespace.